# Trying to save data using typeORM in mssql server, Err: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: node.js, nest

facing Error: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.

In body I am sending an array of object of length 438.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Length of parameter list = sum of all objects properties in an array

note: the sum of properties also includes the subproperties if you have an eager relationship eg. user has a name password, and an address which has 3 properties. so each user has 5 paramters.

if each item in your array has 5 properties, you'll have 2190 parameters.

Have a look at the `chuck` option in the [Typeorm Docs](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/interfaces/_repository_saveoptions_.saveoptions.html#chunk)